# sitecore pageedit mode xslt rendering

Tags: c#, xslt, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a sitecore site and I have a rendering PageBody (xslt).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:sc="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" 
  xmlns:dot="http://www.sitecore.net/dot"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dot sc">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:param name="lang" select="'en'"/>
<xsl:param name="id" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="sc_item"/>
<xsl:param name="sc_currentitem"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$sc_item" mode="main"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--==============================================================-->
<!-- main                                                         -->
<!--==============================================================-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
  <div>
    <sc:html field="Body Text" select="."/>
  </div> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I'd like to be able to edit the content of Body Text on the page edit mode. What am I missing?
Cheers

Comment: What is rendering on page your code? It's rendering just div without Body Text?

Comment: <code type='text/sitecore'chromeType='placeholder'kind='open' id='_wrapperinner_two'key='/wrapperinner/two' class='scpm' data-selectable='false'>{"com":[],"contextItemUri":"sc://master/{.}?lang=en&ver=13","custom":{"allowedRenderings":],"editable":"false"},"displayName":"two","expandedDName":null}</code><code type='text/sitecore' chromeType='rendering' kind='open' hintName='Page Body' id='.' class='scpm'data-selectable='false'>{"com":[],"contextItemUri":"sc://master/.lng=en&ver=13","custom":{"renderingID":".","editable":"true"},"displayName":"Page Body","expandedDisplayName":null}</code>

Comment: sorry but I had to remove some tags because was... too long?

Comment: If you have a choice, you should really stop using XSLT and just use User Controls or MVC views instead. XSLT support is being dropped (Microsoft already has and Sitecore does not recommend the use of it anymore).

Comment: What is the html content in your `Body Text` field? Make sure your HTML is valid, same with any code surrounding your control, the Page Editor gets really messed up with invalid HTML. I strongly agree with Ruud about not using XSLT though.

Comment: Ruud van Falier and jammykam... So, just to be sure if I understand, there is no way to do it through xslt? I'll need to create for each xslt a user control? On this user control I can just put a Field Renderer and this will allow to edit the content through the Page Editor? Thank you very much

Comment: Of course it is possible, it is just not the recommended practice any more esp for SC7. The code you have posted _should_ work though.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at next link about [xslt](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/presentationcomponentxslreference-usletter.pdf).

Can you check if your rendering has a datasource?
If your rendering  has a datasource than "." will point to that datasource item not to current item.

Comment: Hey climber... For what I understand it has datasource because I see the content on preview...

Comment: It's really strange if you say it's showing on preview but not on page editor, do you have javascript on the page ?

Comment: You can have conflicts between your js and javascript from Sitecore

Comment: Sorry... I might explained wrong... It displays on Page Editor mode too... But I'd like to be able to edit the content through the Page Editor and currently I'm only allowed to do it through the content editor.